# Border color not changing

Tags: html, css

Ive created a div. On the right border of the div theres a border image and on the left border I want to have colored border. The problem is when I change the color it is not appearing. How can I fix this?
This is my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qu2odas4/4/)

CSS:

```
div{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#EA6E0E;
    border-image-slice: 0 31 0 0; 
    border-image-width: 0px 20px 0px 0px; 
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 7px 0px; 
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch; 
    border-image-source: url("http://i.imgur.com/pN8TPVw.jpg?1");

    border-radius:8px;
    border-left:8px solid #000; //NOT WORKING
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set a border-image and a border-left, what you could do is give a left-border and then instead of a border-image you just create a div that acts as a border. Do this by giving the parent div (the one with the border) `position: relative;` (so all his child elements are relative to his position) and the border-div a `height: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; width: 20px;`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qu2odas4/5/)